# Python 2.7.14 ,code not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting error ,expected an indented block.

```
 n = input("enter any number")
 for i in range(1,n+1):
 print i,
```

Comment: print should be inside for loop (refer: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) , fixed your code in question itself

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: In programming languages such as C, CPP, Java etc you use curly braces ({}) to define a code block but python depends on spacing given.

Comment: @MaheshKaria please don't edit the question in such a way that it hides the actual problem.

Comment: Note: The comma after `i` doesn't help much either

Comment: In Python 2 a trailing comma works somewhat like a multi-line string literal (if it follows a `print` statement), I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
n = int(input("enter any number"))
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print i,
```

Use Indentation.